# Cannot understand why 1 is added to each recursive call

Tags: java, recursion

I have been working on a code challenge which asks to keep multiplying the digits of a number until the digits are reduced to a single digit and then return the number of times the multiplication took place. If the argument passed in is a single digit then the method must return 0.

I have solved the problem using a loop, but I would like to understand how to do it using recursion. Below is the code I found that I could understand for the most part except for why 1 is being added to each call? Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks!

```java
public static int persistence(int num) {
    int mul = 1;
    if (num < 10) return 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        mul *= num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return 1 + persistence(mul);   // reason for 1 + method call?
}

persistence(39)  //should return 3
persistence(999) //should return 4
persistence(4)   // should return 0

// 39: 3 * 9 = 27, 2 * 7 = 14, 1 * 4 = 4. Value returned 3
// 4: 4 * 1 = 4. Value returned 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah .. Similar issues arise while learning recursion! The path on which every engineer walks. Let's hold the `1` just in a variable and `persistence(mul)`'s another one. That is,

```
int oneStepResult = persistence(mul); // watch out that the rest of the line is evaluated when returned 0, that is, base case
int isDone = 1;
return oneStepResult + isDone;
```

Try to think it like that. As an advice, whenever you run into difficulty while answering question of "what does the recursion do", try to dissect its method body.

---

with 34

[image]

---

with 39

[image]

Comment: Yes, using the variables and breaking it down really helps. I just want to confirm if I understand it right. Variable `oneStepResult` always points to 0 because `persistense(mul)` isn't returning any value, it's just returning itself, so without the 1 being added to it, `oneStepResult` would always be 0, which is why the 1 is used.

Comment: @KabirGandhiok `Variable oneStepResult always points to 0` is not right. I'll add a picture here to make you understand better.

Comment: `I'll add a picture here to make you understand better`, thanks!

Comment: @KabirGandhiok if they seem too fast, you can see them per frame by uploading to the url, https://en.bloggif.com/gif-extract

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get it now. For example with `persistence(39)` as long as `mul` is 10 or greater, each call starting with `persistence(27)` is added to the call stack as recursion proceeds and the while loop continues, thus reducing the value of `mul`. Then as soon as `mul` is reduced to 4, `persistence(4)` becomes the last call to be added to the stack, which then returns 0 (the exit value) + 1. And then the remaining calls in the stack, `1 + persistence(14) and 1 + persistence(27)` are emptied with 1 + 1 for 14, and 2 + 1 for 27. Hope I've got it right now?

Comment: @KabirGandhiok well said.

Comment: Thanks for helping me through this!

Answer (score 1):

Each time the method is called, it will return 1 + the result of the next method call. Basically, it is counting how many times it has to go through and multiply the numbers. Here is a (simplified) visual showing what gets returned each time:

```
persistence(39) -> 1 + persistence(27)

1 + (persistence(27)) -> 1 + (1 + persistence(14)) -> 2 + persistence(14)

2 + (persistence(14)) -> 2 + (1 + persistence(4)) -> 3 + persistence(4)

3 + (persistence(4)) -> 3 + (0) -> 3
```